# Anastasia "Dee" Dualla Once-Per-Game Ability Timing

Tags: battlestar-galactica

The text on Anastasia "Dee" Dualla's once per game says:

> Once per game, before making a Skill check, look at the top 3 cards of any Skill deck (even outside your Skill set), and add all of them to either the Skill check or your hand.

When is that ability meant to be played in timing?  Before Investigative Committee?  Before Reckless?  Before any players play any cards?  Before Dee plays any cards?  When is it too late to trigger her power in a given skill check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official sequence of events for resolving a Skill Check:

1. Read Card
2. Play Two Cards from Destiny Deck
3. Play Skills
4. Shuffle and Divide Cards
5. Total Strength
6. Determine Result

I've generally interpreted the "before making a skill check" phrase to mean the time between steps 1 and 3 (when the Destiny Deck cards come out usually isn't important). So things like Investigative Committee, Reckless and Dee's ability should ideally be used during this time. However, things sometimes happen a little fast and people start throwing in cards before someone has a chance to announce an action. We're usually pretty lenient and let people do things after step 3 starts if it doesn't seem like they're gaming.

I don't think there's any specific sequence between Investigative Committee, Reckless, Dee's ability, and the like. I think they could happen in any order. Generally we play it kind of loose and the first person to act goes first; normally it doesn't matter. Ideally, everyone that has something to do should indicate that they do. According to the rules, it's up to the currently player to decide the order.